# Function pointer called with free

Tags: list, free, singly-linked-list

I am practicing some programs from a book on Algorithms using C programming.
 I see the following function:

```
void list_init(List *list, void (*destroy)(void *data)) {

/*  Initialize the list. */

list->size = 0;
list->destroy = destroy;
list->head = NULL;
list->tail = NULL;

return;

}
```

which is later called as:

```
list_init(&list, free);
```

I thought `free` is a function in C language that is described as: `void free(void *ptr)` and therefore requires an argument. 
So, why is `free` provided as an argument to `list_init` by itself? Can someone help me understand this please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this one out. The argument to free is provided in another function when list->destroy(data) is called. This is because list->destroy is set to the address of 'free'.